# how to add column to table in controller with bindAggregation ui5

Tags: sapui5

```
 I have created value help
```

What I want is **to add another column of quantity**
Adding it to columns is not a problem because it's total JSON
But putting it in rows is a bit problematic - because I pull the data from the table - the products - they have no quantity.
I want to create this here by invitation
The point is that the code is in the form of oTable.bindAggregation

[image: here is my valuhelp]
this is my code:

```js
onValueHelpRequested: function() {
    var aCols = this.oColModel.getData().cols;
    this._oValueHelpDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("Ztest.Ztest.view.ValueHelpDialogBasic", this);
    this.getView().addDependent(this._oValueHelpDialog);

    this._oValueHelpDialog.getTableAsync().then(function (oTable) {
        oTable.setModel(window.orders);
        oTable.setModel(this.oColModel, "columns");

        if (oTable.bindRows) {
            oTable.bindAggregation("rows", "/Items");
        }

        if (oTable.bindItems) {
            oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/Items", function () {
                return new ColumnListItem({
                    cells: aCols.map(function (column) {
                        return new Label({ text: "{" + column.template + "}" });
                    })
                });
            });
        }
        this._oValueHelpDialog.update();
    }.bind(this));

    this._oValueHelpDialog.setTokens(this._oMultiInput.getTokens());
    this._oValueHelpDialog.open();
},
```

have I a control here to insert step input into each row?
I mean such a thing like:
[image: what mind input step]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because  it Unable to log in second if if (oTable.bindItems) pereps because oTable.setModel(this.oColModel, "columns");
I made it as

```
`onValueHelpRequested: function() {
            var aCols = this.oColModel.getData().cols;
            this._oValueHelpDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("Ztest.Ztest.view.ValueHelpDialogBasic", this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._oValueHelpDialog);

            this._oValueHelpDialog.getTableAsync().then(function (oTable) {
                oTable.setModel(window.orders);
                oTable.setModel(this.oColModel, "columns");
                 var oColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Qty"}),
                        template: new sap.m.StepInput({value: "{Qty}"}),
                        width: "70px",
                        step:"1",
                        largerStep:"1",
                        max:"35",
                        min:"0",
                        stepMode:"Multiple" 
                });

                if (oTable.bindRows){
                    oTable.addColumn(oColumn);
                    oTable.bindAggregation("rows", "/Items");
                }

                /*if (oTable.bindItems) {
                        oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/Items", function () {
                        return new ColumnListItem({
                                 cells: aCols.map(function (column) {
                                 console.log(column);
                                    if (column.template=="Qty") {
                                        return new StepInput({ text: "{" + column.template + "}" });
                                    } else {
                                        return new Label({ text: "{" + column.template + "}" });
                                    }
                                })
                        });
                    });
                }*/
                this._oValueHelpDialog.update();
            }.bind(this));

            this._oValueHelpDialog.setTokens(this._oMultiInput.getTokens());
            this._oValueHelpDialog.open();
        },
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Your table consists of rows with labels only, because your `ColumnListItem`'s cells are created this way. If you wish to add something else, you need to adapt your factory function. For example:

```js
return new ColumnListItem({
    cells: aCols.map(function (column) {
        if (<condition>) {
            return new StepInput(...);
        } else {
            return new Label({ text: "{" + column.template + "}" });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: but it Unable to log in second if  if (oTable.bindItems)
pereps because oTable.setModel(this.oColModel, "columns");?
what should I do instead?